# How to hide LookUp values

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

In my WinForms project I have two LookUp. Depending on value of the first LookUp, I hide or show the second one.
But when in the first LookUp I select value, which should hide the second one, it hides it but I can see it's values. How can I hide the values too?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could try to add in  `comboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged` event

```
comboBox2.Visible = false;
//or
comboBox2.Enabled = false;
//choose what you need

//Something like:

private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 0)
  {
    comboBox2.Enabled = false;
  }
  else
  {
    comboBox2.Enabled = true;
  }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't helped. I think, maybe I need to set somehow, which element gets focus after I select value in the first LookUp.

Comment: It's right, my answer is add the event when the first select(index change) will trigger, and decide by what it select(select index), to change the second(combox"2")'s enabled or disabled.